# Asyncronous knockout observableArray select options loading

Tags: javascript, ajax, knockout.js, ko.observablearray, html-select

I hava a selectOptions ajax-based asincronous loader; it accepts remote address and returns an observable array, correctly populated with descriptions and keyvalues to be accepted by the following binding

```
 <select data-bind="value: selectedVal, options: opts, optionsText: 'desc', optionsValue:'key', optionsCaption: ''"/></div>
```

The fact is that, being asincronous, when I trigger a select options change, based on some user actions, I assign it to my model observable array, I do not get the select popuated, but remains empty.

```
 mymodel.opts = loadOptions("<remoteaddress>");
```

I know when the second line is called the anwer is not arrived yet, but the returned value is an observableArray, so it should respond correctly whenever is populated, having been assigned to an observable array binded with the ui.

If I hardcode the returned object from the ajax call (when it returns) taking it from console.log in Firefox, or if I pass the observable array opts into the loadOptions, and change it to build up the opts inside it, then it works, but I really need to use loadOptions as is, asincronous. I also tried to append mymodel.opts.valueHasMutated(), but yet ko cannot use the newlly arrived observableArray.

If possible leaving intact the options loader, and if possible without using a custom binding, can I use the incoming observable array for binding when it will be ready?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you've got is that when this line runs:

```
mymodel.opts = loadOptions("<remoteaddress>");
```

it's replacing the entire observable array with a *different* `observableArray`, rather than updating the current one.  You need to update the existing one - can you change `loadOptions` to return a normal array, rather than an observable one?  You can then do:

```
//clear any existing entries
mymodel.opts.removeAll();
//push the new entries in
mymodel.opts.push.apply(mymodel.opts, loadOptions("<remoteaddress>"));
```

Comment: Can't change it. But even if I could, If it returns a non observable, it would be empty at the time of the asyncronous call, so I won't get any options loaded. It is the same as assigning mymodel.opts(loadOptions("<remoteaddress>")());. It do not populate the options, even if the ajax, later, correctly returns the object

Comment: ah I think I see - does the observableArray it returns get updated at a later time?  Where you have `model.opts = loadOptions...` in the code, is that before applyBindings is called?

Comment: If this is the case, I think you need to show what `loadOptions` itself is doing - I think the problem probably lies in there

Comment: Well, the ajax response comes in later, but does not update the observable array (so the UI). The loader is called after the applyBindings call, the model is loaded and functional, but if the user clicks a button, or another, the select is populated with different records. The loader simply asks the server a json object, made of an array of [{"desc":"description", "key": key"}..., which are pushed one by one (into a $.each cycle) into a newly created observableArray inside the loader, which is then returned. I do not have the code available now.

Comment: It sounds like it's creating a new `observableArray` each time it updates, as well as after the initial `applyBindings` has been called - this isn't going to work as the page is going to be bound to the original array at the point `applyBindings` was called.  You'll need to restructure it in such a way that the *same* `observableArray` is updated rather than creating a new one each time

Comment: Yes, I agree. I tried many ways, but doesn't work, just like the observable array is not observable. The the related UI binding is not binded to the new observable array